# Karate: Loop thru the JSON response and match where arrays order is different

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where a portion of the api response is the response from another api (an api A intern calls another api B). But the response array elements interchange their position in each hit, but the elements are same, only the order changes. In my master feature file im calling api B and doing the validation in a loop like below. But because of the order issue `karate.match` fails. Is there a way I can use `karate.contains`? or any other work around for this?

```
* def apib = call read('apib.feature') __row;

    * def xyz = 
        """
        function(response,apib,status){
            if (status == 200){
                if (karate.sizeOf(apib.response.members) > 1){
                        for (i = 0;i < karate.sizeOf(apib.response.members); i++){
                            karate.match(response.member.id[0].covered[i].Uid, apib.response.members[i].member.Uid);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        """
        * def apib = all.responseStatus
        * def var = xyz(response,apib,status)
```

Comment: closed as duplicate, if you still don't get a solution, ask a new question, and this time provide a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example